# Conditionally mapping column names to row values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Assume that we have a table where we have one field for zip code and the rest are binary fields (1 or NULL) with names corresponding to various places. For example, imagining the table has 201 fields with the first field titled "zip code" containing zip codes and the latter being 200 binary value fields titled with city names: Chicago, New York, Houston, etc.

Assume that row one contains zip code 11373. While one could use coalesce to find the first non-null value and return "New York" another value like "Elmhurst" may also be true.

```
zip_code  new_york  chicago  elmhurst  dover  maspeth
10001        1        NULL     NULL    NULL    NULL
07801       NULL      NULL     NULL     1      NULL
11373        1        NULL      1      NULL     1
```

The goal is to map the column names to each respective zip code and get an output like so:

```
zip_code    city
 10001     new_york
 07801     dover
 11373     new_york
 11373     elmhurst
 11373     maspeth
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for SQL UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT unpvt.*
FROM 
    #x UNPIVOT (v FOR statename IN (new_york, chicago,elmhurst, dover, maspeth)) AS unpvt
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select zip_code, 'New York' as city from t where new_york = 1
union all
select zip_code, 'Chicago' as city from t where chicago = 1
union all
. . .
```